# How do I create a network bridge between WLAN and Ethernet on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, bridge, wlan

I have a nice not-too-old laptop and I'm running FreeBSD 12.1 Stable on it.

I want to share my internet connection from my Wireless card to whatever I connect to the Ethernet slot on this computer.

Edit: this is how my interfaces are configured:

Ethernet (**em0**) - no particular configuration, if I plug an Ethernet cable  into this port, connect it to my network switch, and then run `dhclient em0` it immediately receives and IP address.

WLAN (**wlan0**) - configured using wpa_supplicant, and has an active and working DHCP client. Connected to the network via a Unifi access-point which is in its turn connected to a DNS/DHCP and gateway server running pfSense.

The FreeBSD official documentation for [bridging](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-bridging.html) doesn't really work in this case. This is what I've tried:

```
ifconfig bridge create
ifconfig bridge0 addm wlan0 addm em0 up
ifconfig wlan0 up
ifconfig em0 up
```

Then when I run `dhclient bridge0`, it simply doesn't get an IP address. Setting a static IP address for bridge0 doesn't help either..

There are some places online (specifically the FreeBSD forums) where people say this is not possible technically, is there a way to check that? Does anyone else have any insights on this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. How do you configure your Ethernet interface? Do you have a DHCP server for this network? Do you use static IP addresses? Do you use a different IP range with corresponding network configuration for WLAN and Ethernet? This might be useful: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/trying-to-set-up-a-network-bridge-for-dhcp.20287/

Comment: There's a technical limitation unrelated to BSD: the AP doesn't (at least by default) send or accept 4 MACs addresses frames, it usually handles 3 MACs (ethernet uses only 2 MACs). Having the client using a bridge requires a 4 MACs mode or some proprietary equivalent mode. See this Q/A to understand what it's about: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header . If FreeBSD *is* the AP then it's possible. If it's the client, forget about it that would be very difficult. To remember: wifi is not ethernet.

Comment: @Bodo edited and added information about existing interfaces. The link does not help and it seems to refer to 2 ethernet ports. The link does not help, FreeBSD doesn't seem to know what to do with SYNDHCP.

Comment: If you want to share your wireless connection with the local ethernet LAN, the most straightforward way is via NAT.  Run `natd` on your wireless interface, install a minimal NAT-capable `ipfw` ruleset, and set `sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`.  Optionally, you may wish to run a `dhcpd` instance on the ethernet interface to serve IPs to DHCP clients on the local LAN.

Comment: Some pointers that may help discover your best choices [wlan(4)](https://manpages.me/?wlan) (and SEE ALSO at the bottom). [ifconfig(8)](https://manpages.me/?ifconfig) @JimL. makes a good suggestion. But I'd choose [pf(4)](https://manpage.me/?pf); see also [pf.conf(5)](https://manpage.me/?pf.conf) with maybe `cloned_interfaces="wlan0"` with `nat` and `rdr` pass entries in `pf.conf`. I think the `cloned_interfaces` is the closest of the options available to your stated configuration.